# How to create a RSS feed from a Facebook list?

Tags: facebook, rss

I am currently looking for a way to create a RSS feed from a Facebook list (for example a collection of groups and pages collected together to a list by a user).

A Facebook list has the following URL pattern:

`https://www.facebook.com/lists/17845112701005975`

Does anyone know how to create or generate a RSS feed from such a list?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a way.

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-an-RSS-feed-of-a-Facebook-List - It's not a solution, but a workaround of sorts.